# Why is my hidden <tr> not really hidden?

Tags: jquery, visible

I have this simple html markup generated from classic asp:

```
<table>
  <tr class="trClass">
    <td>Hello </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class ="trClass">
    <td>World!</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

If i set the tr belonging to Hello to hide() using Jquery it hides. Good!

But, when i use this $('.trClass:visible').each(function() { alert('visible') });
it shows the output 'visible' twice.

Why is this?

My problem here is that im filtering a table on a column with a selection box. But after filtering i need to perform some calculations on those rows that are visible in the table, but i get all rows right now.

Any ideas?

/Daniel

Comment: can you provide a demo page plz ?

Answer (score 13):

The `:visible` selector does not test the `display` style property, you want to use [`:hidden`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) instead, [the 1.3.2 release notes say](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#:visible.2F:hidden_Overhauled):

> ...if your element's CSS display is
>   "none", or any of its parent/ancestor
>   element's display is "none", or if the
>   element's width is 0 and the element's
>   height is 0 then an element will be
>   reported as hidden.

These will correctly select your visible rows:

```
$('.trClass:not(:hidden)').each(function() { 
    alert('visible'); 
});
```

or:

```
$('.trClass').each(function() { 
    if(!$(this).is(':hidden')) {
        alert('visible'); 
    }
});
```

or:

```
$('.trClass').filter('not:(:hidden)').each(function() { 
    alert('visible');
});
```

`hide` sets the style to `display="none"`. The [release notes](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#:visible.2F:hidden_Overhauled) for jQuery 1.3.2 also say:

> In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible
>   if its browser-reported offsetWidth or
>   offsetHeight is greater than 0.

so I guess in this case the `:visible` selector is erroneously not matching anything because the rows are not occupying any space according to the calculations performed, despite the fact that their CSS `display` property is *not* set to `none`. Conversely, `:hidden` correctly matches elements with `style="display:none"` so testing for non `:hidden` elements works just fine.

Comment: Neither `:hidden` nor `:visible` check the display property. Check the source yourself: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L957

Comment: It's a legitimate bug according to Resig himself: http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Bug-with-:hidden-selector-and-tbody-in-Internet--Explorer-p24631644s27240.html

Comment: Nice edit (removed downvote), although you still *imply* `:hidden` checks the `display` property.

Answer (score 4):

[You've found a legitimate bug](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4512). It's broken in 1.3.2 but now [fixed in trunk](http://dev.jquery.com/changeset/6413).

[According to  Resig](http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Bug-with-:hidden-selector-and-tbody-in-Internet--Explorer-p24631644s27240.html):

> we already look for the case of 'tr'
>   which has the same problem, in IE

Thought you'd like to know...

Comment: @spx2: regression in 1.3.2. Prior versions checked the `display` property. 1.3.2 used a trick to check the [lack of] dimensions of the element. See @karim79's first quote.

Comment: @spx2 - As usual, it was programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this matters, but doesn't hide() set `display: none;` and not `visible: hidden`? Meaning that a hidden row is still visible, it just isn't displayed...

Answer (score 0):

most likely your trClass collides with the display: none that .hide() sets.
when a tag has both class attribute and style attribute only on will be applied.
you should inpsect closely your trClass and take out display: stuff from it.