# Why does jQuery's :visible selector include hidden TRs on IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

jQuery's [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector seems not to work on TR elements in Internet Explorer 8 in the sense that includes TRs that have been hidden with [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  Here is a test case:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
               $('#trb').hide();
               $('#trcount').html($('tr:visible').length);
               $('#pb').hide();
               $('#pcount').html($('p.item:visible').length);
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr id="trb"><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C</td></tr>
    </table>
    <p><span id="trcount">?</span> rows are visible.</p>

    <p>Using paragraphs:</p>
    <p class="item">A</p>
    <p class="item" id="pb">B</p>
    <p class="item">C</p>

    <p><span id="pcount">?</span> paragraphs are visible.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome, it results in “2 rows are visible” and “2 paragraphs are visible,” as expected.  On Internet Explorer 8, however, the result is “3 rows are visible” and “2 paragraphs” are visible.

Why?  And what is the best way to work around it?  (The best I can think of it to add a CSS class when I hide an item.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: My jsFiddle inf IE8 ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Cc3eM/ ---------- My screenshot ==> http://i.imgur.com/1xYYW.png

Comment: @Peter Ajtai - the op is using 1.3.2 - although I still cannot reproduce

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/eAMsP/ you are right IE8 returns a different length.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai it works in jQuery 1.4.2 but not in jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: See the answers for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486523/why-is-my-hidden-tr-not-really-hidden Looks like it was a 1.3.2 bug.

Comment: @redsquare - Thanks for spotting that. It looks like that's clearly the problem. I could reproduce it w 1.3.2.... but only in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with jQuery 1.3.2. To solve the problem use jQuery 1.4.2.

To observe the difference compare these two jsFiddles **in IE** 8:

**[jQuery 1.4.2 - no problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xYYW.png)**
[image]

**[jQuery 1.3.2 - "3 rows visible"](http://jsfiddle.net/Buuwe/)**
[image]

As Patrick DW points out in the comments, **[this answer points out the specific bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486523/why-is-my-hidden-tr-not-really-hidden/1487314#1487314)**. There's an answer in that same thread that seems to imply that using `not:(:hidden)` would solve the problem in 1.3.2, but it doesn't.